# How to make an app that gives me name by writing the ID

Tags: c#

I need to make a console app using arrays
I have to declare an array with few names and another array with few IDs  and then I have to make the app
to ask me write  the ID and it displays the name of the current ID (0 positioned name has 0 positioned ID and so on)
and if the typed ID is not correct I need to get an answer that the ID doesn't exist also I loops should be used to know which ID goes to which name 
ok here is the code and I Don't know what to do more 
{fak y'all for downvoting}

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] names ={ "Endrit", "Endrit1", "Endrit2", "Endrit3", "Endrit4", "Endrit5", "Endrit6" };
            string[] ID = { "001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007" };

            Console.Write("Type the ID :");
            string IDN = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking us to code it for you? I hope not. Show us what you got and what you tried.

Comment: Sounds like homework?

Comment: Ok. So what is your question? There are many examples of exactly what you're talking about on this site. Which part are you stuck on? Please show the code you have so far and let us know where you need help.

Comment: Well, for starters, you should be using objects there's no relation between the 2 arrays. I suggest you read more into C# and OOP.

Comment: @12seconds but I have to make a relation between them using indexes I Don't know how

Comment: Why do you have to? Homework assignment on arrays? If not homework, then what's stopping you from doing objects? Clients don't tell us how to code.

Comment: no dude its not homework I am just trying to learn c# today in class we did something like that but I was sitting behind and I couldn't see anything so I didn't understand well how it worked.... @12seconds and what do you mean objects ? we learned loops , if statement , arrays and with that teacher said you can do it

Comment: Sorry if I sounded rude, but to answer your question. You don't need `string[] ID`, each value in `names` have `index`, so you would just apply that index like `names[0]` which would be `Endrit`

Comment: Objects will come later, this is a normal progression to learning them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.IndexOf` to get the index of a particular item in an array. If the item is not found, it will return `-1`.

So, you can just find the index of the user input in the `ID` array, and return the item at the same index in the `names` array:

```
// Get the index in the ID array of the item the user entered
int indexOfUserEntry = Array.IndexOf(ID, IDN);

// If the item was found (index is > -1) show the item at the same index in the names array
if (indexOfUserEntry > -1) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("The name for that id is: " + names[indexOfUserEntry]);
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("The specified Id does not exist");
}

Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```